# how to safely remove usb external drive on ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: usb, nautilus

I ran critical and recommended updates today on 22.04.4.
After the update, I connected my Seagate drive and ran backup.
When the backup finished, I opened the context menu for the drive in Nautilus and found that the Safely Remove command was not in the list although it has been there on all previous uses of the drive. There is a Remove command in the menu but it is grayed out.
Safely Remove would unmount *AND* power down the drive. The unmount command now appearing in the menu leaves the drive spinning. It has been my experience than unplugging a usb drive while it's still spinning can cause problems.
I found udisksctl commands to unmount and power-off from the command line so I have a work around, but -
Is it possible to get Safely Remove back in the context menu?

Comment: I use command line tools for unmounting partitions on external drives. Actually I use 'only' `umount` or aliases containing `umount`, but I know `udisksctl`, and if you prefer that because it can also turn off power of the device, good :-) I would not bother about getting the eject icon back into your GUI. You could make things more convenient by creating an alias for the command line and store it in `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Ran my backup program again today and when it was finished and I was ready to remove the drive, right-click on the drive in Nautilus gave me the Safely Remove option again. Perhaps something in the backup program affects how Nautilus sees the drive? Anyway, since I have the workaround in udisksctl, I'll call this resolved. Doesn't seem worth more troubleshooting.